# User profiles are not created after full synchronization in UPS on Sharepoint for some subdomains in AD forest

Tags: sharepoint

User profiles are not created after full synchronization in UPS on Sharepoint for some subdomains in AD forest.
I have A domain and 10 subdomains. Only users from 7 subdomains sync via Sharepoint UPS.
There are no errors in miisclient.exe:
Delta Synchronization for domain A1
Start 02.12.2020 11:04:40
Partition: DC=A1,DC=A,DC=local
End 02.12.2020 11:04:40
Status: success
and A2, A3 success too.
Kind regards, Vasily Zaytsev

Answer (score 0):

In your question not have enouf information about import settings.
First of all, Microsoft not recomended import from root AD container. You must select container only with users and groups.
Second - all errors of UPS import you can find in ULS logs, and you can check state of import and errors in
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe"

If you have several servers in farm, you can use [Merge-SPLogFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/merge-splogfile?view=sharepoint-ps) to collect logs from all servers.

Comment: The problem was with Replication Security permission for 3 others domain. Thank's a lot!